# Can I log multi-engine time abroad, when I'm not rated for multi in that country?

Tags: faa-regulations, logging, international

I hold a multi-engine FAA CPL and want to fly a multi-engine aircraft in another country. The aircraft is not N-registered and I don't have a multi-engine rating in that country. Can I log the time in my FAA logbook? I'd like to log the hours under my FAA license.

More Details:
Country: Colombia (ICAO)
Role: Second in Command

The plane is a multi, I don't have multi license from the registration's country but I have FAA Multi license, so the idea is to fly it and log the hours using my FAA license can I do that ? Even if I don't have the license to fly that plane from the country of the registration ?

Comment: I'm a little confused by the last part, how are you going to fly the plane in another country, but you can't legally fly it in that country? In what role are you flying? PIC? SIC?

Comment: It also matters what country you are flying in, you may only log hours in foreign registered aircraft if that aircraft is registered (and airworthy) in an ICAO member state. The short answer is that you would log the hours as if you were flying in the US, no different. The "wrench" is your last sentence and what it really means.

Comment: This seems like a similar case to [this one](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/33114/62).

Comment: A few more details might be useful: which other country is it; do you have a license there too; is your aim to log PIC time?

Comment: I voted to re-open: the question is specifically about logging time for which the pilot is rated in the US but not abroad. The other question is about how to physically record/manage information in both US and foreign logbooks. Those are completely different things.

Comment: If the a/c is not N-registered and you don't have the rating from that country that probably means you're acting as PIC or SIC illegally. If the country allows you to operate the aircraft then I see no reason why you can't log the time. There is a place in your logbook to put the a/c registration, US or otherwise.

Comment: Do you have a Colombian license of any kind, or not?

Comment: Yes I Have, I Hold Colombian Comercial License...But Single Engine

Answer (score 1):

FAR 61.3 stipulates what is required to fly N-registered aircraft outside the united States.  There is nothing about flying non N-registered aircraft outside the U.S.  Rightfully so, the FAA does not have jurisdiction in that case.

To answer your question, you will need to reference that country's rule.  If they are an ICAO country, the rules are probably very similar.