# Can a US PPL holder log ASES time in Canada while flying with a local FI?

Tags: faa-regulations, logging

I am an FAA PPL, and I'll be visiting Canada. I'd like to log some seaplane time while I'm there. Can I log ASES dual-received time with any Canadian instructor, or do they need to hold an FAA CFI certificate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, [you can log time in foreign aircraft.](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/154/62) For training time specifically, the foreign instructor must hold an ICAO-compliant license, per [14 CFR 61.41](https://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/retrieveECFR?gp&r=PART&n=14y2.0.1.1.2#se14.2.61_141).

So it should be no problem in your situation.