# Can I log flight training outside the US in a US-registered aircraft?

Tags: faa-regulations, flight-training

I work outside the USA. I have access to fly an airplane with work. I'm working on my instrument rating. Can the time I'm flying be used towards my instrument rating requirements? We always fly on an IFR flight plan and I can fly "under the hood." The guys that I'm working with are all CFII and willing to sign my log book and the a/c have N tail numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The FAA [doesn't care where you fly](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/154/62), and you can even log training time [with a foreign instructor](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/41084/62). Logging time in a US aircraft overseas is completely fine.