# Can I get an FAA restricted ATP certificate with 1000 hours total time?

Tags: faa-regulations, pilot-certification

I have an FAA Commercial Single-Engine certificate with 260 hours total time and a Bachelor's degree in Electrical Engineering issued in Indonesia. I have an Indonesian Passport and I'm working as a copilot flying DHC-6 Twin Otters in Indonesia. I'm planning to get a restricted ATP certificate in the USA but there's a question.

Is it possible to go and get a restricted ATP in the USA after flying 1000 hours TT on DHC 6 Twin Otter in Indonesia?

Comment: Are you talking about *traning* in the US or getting an actual FAA ATPL?

Comment: I'm talking about training in the US. I've seen many Nepali Pilots came to the US and getting an FAA ATP training and license with Piper Seneca. The thing is, they have 1500 hours TT before starting the training (that's what they told me). Me, since I have a bachelor degree, I'm thinking about starting the same training like those guys but only with 1000 hours TT. Is it possible?

Comment: I changed "ATPL" to "restricted ATP" (or R-ATP, if you prefer), because the FAA doesn't use the term ATPL, as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you were trained through a military flight school, the answer is no.  Part 61 states that you need a minimum 1500 hors TT to apply for an ATPL unless you either attended a military flight training program or an aviation degree from an accredited institution.

Answer (score 1):

The regulations on restricted ATP (R-ATP) certificates are in [14 CFR 61.160](https://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/retrieveECFR?gp=&r=PART&n=14y2.0.1.1.2#se14.2.61_1160) and it is possible to get one with 1000hrs but only if you attended an FAA-approved school for training. The 1000-hour option is in 61.160(b) and in summary the civilian requirements are:

- Hold a Bachelor's degree with an aviation major from an FAA-approved school
- Complete 60hrs of FAA-approved coursework
- Hold a commercial certificate and instrument rating, both from a Part 141 course

Based on what you've said, it seems unlikely that you meet those requirements so you wouldn't be able to apply for an R-ATP. There's more information [from the FAA](https://www.faa.gov/pilots/training/atp/) and [this article](http://www.boldmethod.com/blog/2013/08/1500-hour-rule-restricted-atp/) has a useful overview.

The 'good' news is that your flying time in Indonesia can almost certainly be used to meet the FAA's requirements; they usually [don't care where you log time](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/154/62).