# Can I get a restricted ATP based on part 61 training?

Tags: faa-regulations, airline-pilot

I graduated from a college with 60 credits that are related to aviation but I got my IR and CPL from out of school which is part 61. Am I still qualified as a candidate who can apply for a 1000hr R-ATP?

Comment: It's not really a dupe but [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/52486/62) probably covers the same information. See [this answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/52508/62) in particular.

Answer (score 1):

Part [61.160](https://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?SID=392383f9d956a5afd2b323fe6a3ff7d1&mc=true&node=se14.2.61_1160&rgn=div8) says no:

> (b) A person may apply for an airline transport pilot certificate with
>   an airplane category multiengine class rating or an airline transport
>   pilot certificate concurrently with an airplane type rating with a
>   minimum of 1,000 hours of total time as a pilot if the person:
>
> (1) Holds a Bachelor’s degree with an aviation major from an
>   institution of higher education, as defined in §61.1, that has been
>   issued a letter of authorization by the Administrator under §61.169;
>
> (2) Completes 60 semester credit hours of aviation and
>   aviation-related coursework that has been recognized by the
>   Administrator as coursework designed to improve and enhance the
>   knowledge and skills of a person seeking a career as a professional
>   pilot;
>
> (3) Holds a commercial pilot certificate with an airplane category and
>   instrument rating if:
>
> (i) The required ground training was completed as part of an approved
>   part 141 curriculum at the institution of higher education; and
>
> (ii) The required flight training was completed as part of an approved
>   part 141 curriculum at the institution of higher education or at a
>   part 141 pilot school that has a training agreement under §141.26 of
>   this chapter with the institution of higher education; and
>
> (4) Presents official transcripts or other documentation acceptable to
>   the Administrator from the institution of higher education certifying
>   that the graduate has satisfied the requirements in paragraphs (b)(1)
>   through (3) of this section.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I don’t believe you are.  The rule for 1000-hour restricted ATP is that you have to graduate from an approved four-year part 141 university with a commercial license earned at that school.  BoldMethod describes it pretty well:

https://www.boldmethod.com/blog/2013/08/1500-hour-rule-restricted-atp/

There’s also a link towards the bottom of that page that leads to the FAA, which explains the exceptions.